# How to dispose a task in List<Task>

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I use Winform and I'm want to be run non-async but the return is not disposed.
Anyone can help me?

```
public class MyExample : IDisposable
{
    private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        // Track your async Tasks
        tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseAsync());
        tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseAsync());
        tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseAsync());

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingElseAsync()
    {
        if(false){
          //handle dispose
          return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "handle dispose" mean in this scenario? What do you think needs to be disposed? If you mean `MyExample`, then normally the code that owns the instance of `MyExample` would be repsonsible for calling `.Dispose()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm learning c# and my English bad. I have found use cancellationTokenSource.cancel();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example your class doesn't need to implement IDisposable because of the tasks:

```
public class MyExample
{
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();    

        // Track your async Tasks
        tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseAsync());
        tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseAsync());
        tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseAsync());

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingElseAsync()
    {
        if(false){
          return;
        }
    }
}
```

If you're planning to stop before the tasks are finished you should make the tasks be able to accept and use cancellation tokens.

Generally, tasks don't need to be disposed: [Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/).